# How to pass an argument to the listener function passed in addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
anItem.addEventListener("click", iRespond, false);
```

problem is, I need to pass iRespond an argument because iRespond is supposed to handle clicks on many many items and I need a way of distinguishing between items.

How can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple closure:

```
var foo = "bar";
e.addEventListener('whee',function(evt){
  iRespond(evt,foo);
},false);
```

When a simple closure won't do (because you're latching onto a variable that's changing, such as in a loop) you need to create a new closure over that value:

```
foo.addEventListener('bar',(function(jim){
  return function(evt){
    iRespond(evt,jim); // Surprise surprise, jim is available here!
  }
})(someValueToBeNamedJim), false);
```

For example:

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
for (var i=buttons.length;i--;)}
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click',(function(j){
    return function(){ alert("You clicked on button #"+j); };
  })(i),false);
}
```

*You can choose to name the variable the same both inside and outside the function without issue—e.g. using `i` instead of `j` above—but you may find yourself getting confused.*

Answer (score 2):

Nobody seems to be offering the simplest solution.  Put your other function call in an anonymous function like this:

```
anItem.addEventListener("click", function() {
    iRespond(your arg here);
}, false);
```

Or, in many cases, you can just reference the `this` pointer in the event listener to see what object you were called from:

```
anItem.addEventListener("click", iRespond, false);
```

Then, in `iRespond`:

```
function iRespond() {
    // this points to the item that caused the event so you can 
    // determine which one you are processing and then act accordingly
    // For example, this.id is the id of the object
}
```

Comment: +1 for noting the scoping of `this` possibly being helpful (despite the fact that I do believe my answer covers your first point).

Comment: @Phrogz - your answer as it stands now wasn't visible to me when I typed mine.

Answer (score 1):

There are many possibilities. No1 would be creating a closure for it. You also could use [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

A better solution might be to distinguish the options (per item) by the `target` property of the event, which is also passed to the listener. This will become very elegant when you're using only one handler for many items, e.g. adding it to the `<ul>` instead of one for every `<li>` element. Then choose what to do e.g by id or data-attributes of the target element.

Comment: +1 for using the `target` and suggesting binding to a common ancestor.