# addEventListener firing multiple times for the same handle when passing in arguments with anonymous function

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, addeventlistener, anonymous-function

For some reason, the event listener is firing twice for each element when passing arguments into an anonymous function. I.e., the click event on element `el` will register once and, thus, fire once.

```
el.addEventListener("click", handle, false);
el.addEventListener("click", handle, false);
```

But if I want to pass my own arguments to it, it will register and fire twice.

```
el.addEventListener("click", function() { handle(event, myArgument); }, false);
el.addEventListener("click", function() { handle(event, myArgument); }, false);
```

The question is why and what's the solution?

I looked elsewhere and cannot seem to find a solution or understand why this problem is occurring. I tried implementing the solutions in [How to pass an argument to the listener function passed in addEventListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307136/how-to-pass-an-argument-to-the-listener-function-passed-in-addeventlistener) but they did not help --

I did the basic anonymous function or closure and then the more advanced version, which is the shown below but it did work.

I don't get why passing no arguments causes the element event to register once and passing arguments causing the element event to register twice.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var handle_2 = function(evt, type) {
                var test;
                switch (type) {
                    case "focus": 
                        console.log(evt.target.value);
                        break;
                    case "click":
                        console.log(evt.target.id + " was clicked");
                        break;
                    default: console.log("no type found");
                }
            };
        
            window.onload = function() {
                var textbox = document.getElementById("t1");
                var button = document.getElementById("btn");
                textbox.value = "456";
                button.value = "Press";

                var typeFocus = "focus", typeClick = "click";

                textbox.addEventListener("focus", (function(typeFocus) { return function(evt) { handle_2(evt, typeFocus); }})(typeFocus), false);
                button.addEventListener("click", (function(typeClick) { return function(evt) { handle_2(evt, typeClick); }})(typeClick), false);
                
                // Registers again for each element. Why?
                textbox.addEventListener("focus", (function(typeFocus) { return function(evt) { handle_2(evt, typeFocus); }})(typeFocus), false);
                button.addEventListener("click", (function(typeClick) { return function(evt) { handle_2(evt, typeClick); }})(typeClick), false);
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <input id="t1" type="text" />
            <input id="btn" type="button" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you even calling `el.addEventListener` twice?

Comment: It's outside of the scope of the discussion. It has to do with some vendor code I'm working on.

Comment: If you call `addEventListener()` twice on the same element, the listener will run twice.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The simplest solution is to create the new handler only once:

```
var newHandle = function(event) { handle(event, myArgument); };

el.addEventListener("click", newHandle, false);
el.addEventListener("click", newHandle, false);
```

If you call `addEventListener` multiple times on the same element with exactly the same values for event type, handler and capture then the handler is only registered once. From the [DOM spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#add-an-event-listener):

> ...
> 5. If *eventTarget*’s event listener list does not contain an event listener whose type is *listener*’s type, callback is *listener*’s callback, and capture is *listener*’s capture, then append *listener* to *eventTarget*’s event listener list.
> ...

Comment: Thank you very much. Yup, this worked perfectly. I could also remove the listener with this method. I understand now why it was not working before. Thanks again.

Comment: @nim: your event handler

Comment: @FelixKling handler is a function or that?

Comment: @user717236 how do you remove the listener? Just using `el.removeEventListener("click", newHandle)`, or?

Comment: it's working for me , how can add this  inside the normal angular component

Comment: Can you explain why this makes a difference?

Answer (score 9):

Well,,

```
el.addEventListener("click", handle, false);
el.addEventListener("click", handle, false);
```

Registers to the same function "handle()"

```
el.addEventListener("click", function() { handle(event, myArgument); }, false);
el.addEventListener("click", function() { handle(event, myArgument); }, false);
```

Registers "function() { handle(event, myArgument)"... which are two unique anonymous functions. Thus it will fire twice.

Although I don't fully understand why you would want to register it twice, the solution would be to create a function returning your function that takes parameters.

```
el.addEventListener("click", crateHandle(myArgument), false);

var createHandle = function(myArgument) {
  return function(event) {
    .... do something
  };
}
```

It still doesn't solve the fire twice issue though.

Comment: Hmm, because the reference is different? So, how do I pass arguments to a listener and guarantee that it will only register once? Thank you.

Comment: Your solution has the same problem if `el.addEventListener("click", crateHandle(myArgument), false);` is called twice.

Comment: It has to do with some code creating by a vendor that I have to modify. I'm adding an event listener to a few of their local functions. Let's just say if I could do it another way so as to avoid multiple event listeners, I would. Thank you very much.

Comment: yes, since 

return function(event) {
    .... do something
  };

Is still an anonymous function... Sorry, I have no solution for you then other then re-consider registering it twice. It doesn't make sense to do that if you don't want it to fire twice. You should removeEventListener before registering it again.

Comment: No problem. I appreciate your honesty and your kindly help! How would I call removeEventListener in this context? Since I'm passing arguments to the event listener, I imagine I would need to ensure the reference is the same when calling removeEventListener. Thank you again.

Comment: Usually you have to save a reference to the function you created and remove it. I guess you could also save your "myArgument" as a global variable and access it through the handle function.

Comment: Hello guys, you can save references to handlers using `WeakMap` by mapping node -> handler.

Answer (score 2):

`addEventListener` registers as many listeners as it is used.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) it takes 3 arguments, the third is `useCapture` which has nothing to do with registering listener twice or not. It is by default set to `false`, so adding `false` as a third parameter doesn't change much.

Comment: True. But if you read the text in the documentation here, there are cases where it will ignore repeated registrations --
`If multiple identical EventListeners are registered on the same EventTarget with the same parameters, the duplicate instances are discarded. They do not cause the EventListener to be called twice, and since the duplicates are discarded, they do not need to be removed manually with the removeEventListener method.`

Comment: @user3907208: Right. In the first case you pass the same function, so the second one is ignored. In the second case you are passing two different functions.

Comment: Different as in the memory reference, I gather. So, how do I guarantee an event will only be registered once and pass my own arguments? Thank you.

Comment: @user3907208: Call `addEventListener` only once.

Comment: @user3907208: Then you have to store a reference to your new function: `var handler2 = function() { handler(....); };` and use that function instead.

Comment: Sorry, Felix. If I could do it another way, I would. I'm just the messenger who has to make some changes to a vendor's code and this problem came up...oh, store a reference to it. OK, I'll see what I can come with, then. I value your input! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 useEffect(()=>{
        document.addEventListener('keydown', someFunction); 
    }, []);
```

use the useEffect hook, the empty array at the end will till react to not refresh the component once loaded

Comment: useEffect hook is only available in React not JavaScript....