# Click listener fires twice

Tags: javascript, arrays, click, addeventlistener

I'm creating Simon game as Freecodecamp challenge, I finished basic things, now I'm struggling with reseting game. I have a function that reset it, clearing arrays, timeouts etc.

Problem is when I start new game with clicking start button again, it resets, starts new game, but clicking color fires pushing the color twice in player array.

Here is some code: [codepen](https://codepen.io/merko30/pen/aYYBjJ)

```
        function reset() {
        clearTimeout(repeating);
        clearTimeout(genColor);
        pickedColors = []; // computer random colors
        guessingColors = []; //colors that player picks, should match picked ones
        gameOn = false;
        countNumber = 0;  
    }

     function game() {
// Counting
  console.log(pickedColors, guessingColors);
      counter.innerHTML = countNumber;
// New color
          genRandom = setTimeout(() => {
             getRandomColor();
              }, 5);
        guessingColors = [];
 // Add click listener for each color
  for(let i=0; i<colors.children.length; i++) {
    // Guessing

    colors.children[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      if(!running) {
        // Add clicked color to user clicked array
          guessingColors.push(this);
        console.log(guessingColors);
      // Add animation class
        clickClass(this);
      } else {
        e.stopPropagation();
      }

    // repeating.....
```

`running` is a boolean for stopping click listener when computer turn is..

Comment: You've to attach the listeners outside of `game` function, or detach the listeners in `reset` function.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146108/addeventlistener-firing-multiple-times-for-the-same-handle-when-passing-in-argum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ideally it would be removing the event listener when you're done with it or put it outside of the `game()` but here's a quick fix :

use `.onclick` instead of `addEventListener`, this will overwrite the original one instead of adding another event when `game()` is called and you can use `if(colors.children[i].onclick)` elsewhere to check if the element has an event `onclick` attached to it.

line 157 in your PEN becomes : `colors.children[i].onclick = function(e) {`

and remove the `)` on line 204

```js
document.querySelector('#btn').onclick = function() {
  console.log('here');
};

document.querySelector('#btn').onclick = function() {
  console.log('hello'); // this will overwrite the first one
}; 

if (document.querySelector('#btn').onclick)
  console.log('it has an event listener');
else
  console.log('it does not');
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click me</button>
```