# The removeChild(); is removing two inputs? I just need to remove 1 input

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm new to javascript, and currently, I need an individual delete function. I decided to use `variable.removeChild()` but it's deleting 2 inputs

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  document.getElementById("delete").addEventListener("click", function deletes(){
        
    var parent = document.getElementById("list");
        
    var child = parent.getElementsByTagName("li")[0];
        
    console.log(child);
        
    parent.removeChild(child); //deletes a pair of my li inputs
        
    
  });

});
```

Here is how my HTML code looks like

```
<body>
        <h1>LIST</h1>
        <h2>Items: </h2>
        <div>
            <ol id="list">
                <li>test</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <form id="insert">
            <input type="text" id="itemInput" placeholder="Item" name="item">
            <input type="submit" id="add" value="Add">
                
        </form>
        <input type="submit" id="search" value="Search"> //search doesn't do anything yet
        <input type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete first item">  //Here is where it begins

    </body>
```

Here is my other function. I also use addEventListener() perhaps is that the problem?
This code allows me to add list items dynamically to how the user wishes

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
//calls function once #insert has submit a form/hit the input 
document.querySelector('#insert').onsubmit = () => {

    //create variable
    if(document.querySelectorAll('li').length >= 10){
        return false;
    };

    //get the value of the input
    let name = document.querySelector('#itemInput').value;
    //stores value in the h3 tag


    //create element of 'li'
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    //add the contents to the value of 'name'
    li.innerHTML = name;

    //now append the element to the #list section
    document.querySelector('#list').append(li);

    //gets the length of all the list items (li) and stored it in counter
    counter = document.querySelectorAll('li').length;
    //change the h2 tag with the updated list items
    document.querySelector('h2').innerHTML = `Items: ${counter}`;

    //prevents the form from submitting (good for debugging!!!)
    return false;
};
```

});

Comment: could you share what your html looks like?

Comment: Could that event listener be firing multiple times?

Comment: Your function is doing what you want; but maybe this event is called twice.

Comment: Why not just `child.remove()`? https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove

Comment: Do you have 2 inputs in same `li`? Because you're removing the entire `li`.

Comment: Since you have selected `var child = parent.getElementsByTagName("li")[0];` your removechild(child) will be called and it will remove it only once. if looks like eventlistener is getting called multiple times, just add a console.log("how") and check how many times it's been called.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146108/addeventlistener-firing-multiple-times-for-the-same-handle-when-passing-in-argum check this if your event listener is called multiple times

Comment: @KushalSeth actually he already has a console.log(child) so I guess he can already tracks that

Comment: I updated including the HTML and my other function. I did used addEventListener again with a different purpose earlier

Answer (score 0):

Get the list with `document.querySelector('#list')` and the first li by adding `.querySelectorAll('li')[0]`, then find inputs inside.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    document.querySelector('#delete').addEventListener("click", function deletes(){
        let li = document.querySelector('#list').querySelectorAll('li')[0];
        let inputs = li.querySelectorAll('input');
        // Is there any input in li?
        if(inputs.length > 0) {
            // Delete only the first one
            inputs[0].remove();
            // If you want to keep other inputs, just disable the button
            this.disabled = true;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>
     <input type="text" value="input1">
     <input type="text" value="input2">
  </li>
</ul>
<button id="delete">Delete</button>
```

querySelector() and querySelectorAll() lets you find items by id, classname, tagname, attributes, etc. Just like jQuery does. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector